# Backup Rundeck logs: cannot load old logs into new rundeck

Tags: logging, rundeck

when I backup Rundeck projects, I have moved jobs into new Rundeck successfully and copied the /var/logs/rundeck folder into right place of new rundeck server. But I cannot read execution logs on web. 
anyone could help me resolve this problem? let me see the logs of each jobs on web.
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you also need to copy the `/var/lib/rundeck/logs` directory, as the execution logs output is located in that directory. Ref: [framework.logs.dir](https://rundeck.org/docs/administration/configuration/configuration-file-reference.html#framework.properties)

Cheers!

Comment: thank you for your answer, but my framework.logs.dir=var/logs/rundeck rather than  /var/lib/rundeck/logs. so I think the folder /var/lib/rundeck/logs have been already copied .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to restore jobs & execution logs only with import archive.
In project settings you can backup project with "export archive" and restore project with "import archive".
Also available in command line (rd)